# Converting JSON to csv in a useful format

Tags: python, python-requests

I am pretty new to python and started to use **requests** for downloading data.
Up to now I am doing fine, but I always do have issues converting JSON data to csv.

Applying the code below ...

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

url = "https://api.coinstats.app/public/v1/coins?skip=0&limit=100"

payload = {}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

coin_data = json.loads(response.text)
getpost = pd.DataFrame (coin_data)

getpost.to_csv('getpost_1.csv')
```

... I do get data in the plain vanilla JSON format.

My question is and I am starting from scratch: what else has to be done to fix to code getting readable csv-files (without ids and others)?

```
0   {'id': 'bitcoin', 'icon': 'https://static.coin...
1   {'id': 'ethereum', 'icon': 'https://static.coi...
2   {'id': 'binance-coin', 'icon': 'https://static...
3   {'id': 'tether', 'icon': 'https://static.coins...
4   {'id': 'solana', 'icon': 'https://static.coins...
..                                                ...
95  {'id': 'eth_frax3crv-f_0xd632f22692fac7611d2aa...
96  {'id': 'sushi', 'icon': 'https://static.coinst...
97  {'id': 'paxos-standard-token', 'icon': 'https:...
98  {'id': 'compound-governance-token', 'icon': 'h...
99  {'id': 'nem', 'icon': 'https://static.coinstat...

[100 rows x 1 columns]`
```

Bernd

Comment: First try to read your json into a dataframe and check it displays properly. https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-convert-json-into-a-pandas-dataframe-100b2ae1e0d8 - your example json was loaded into one column only and therefore doesn't export like you request.

Comment: With some iterations of the link I managed to fix the issue.